# How to draw curves and straight lines in one image?

Tags: java, android, path, android-canvas, paint

I'm trying to draw what is basically a rounded rectangle plus, a square at one end of it. Sort of like a battery. I have a few restrictions, and it's basically that it must be done using just one paint object and should be able to support a stroke.

This is the code I have so far:

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // myPath outline
    Point[] myPath = { new Point(20, 20), new Point(width, 20), new Point(width, height), new Point(20, height),
            new Point(20, height - 20), new Point(0, height - 20), new Point(0, height - 40),
            new Point(20, height - 40) };

    // Paint
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int color = 0xffff0000;
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    // paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(15));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    // Path moves
    Path path = new Path();

    path.moveTo(myPath[0].x, myPath[0].y);
    int j = myPath.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        path.lineTo(myPath[i].x, myPath[i].y);
    }
    path.close();

    Bitmap toDrawOn;
    toDrawOn = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas ofScreen = new Canvas(toDrawOn);
    ofScreen.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(toDrawOn, 0, 0, paint);

}
```

This gives me a battery shape that I'm looking for, but I have no idea how to round the first 4 corners without rounding the corners of the little square at the end. Again, I need this to be one shape because I need to apply a stroke to it later on. I also can't use a 9patch because I need to change the color programatically.

This is my GOAL:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `path.quadTo` [(the javadoc for it)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#quadTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29). Because this shape is so simple I would just write it out line by line. Heres the start of it.

```
int borderRadius = 15;
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(borderRadius , 0);
path.lineTo(width-borderRadius, 0); // top side
path.quadTo(width, 0, width, borderRadius); // top right corner
path.lineTo(width, height-borderRadius); // right side
path.quadTo(width, height, width-borderRadius, height); // bottom right corner
...
path.close();
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. I will try to complete my shape now. Thanks